# mails sent with Apps Script don't show up in "sent" folder

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, mailmerge

While ago there was an issue with mail merge in gmail. We add to bcc ourselves in order to get a copy of what was sent in our "Sent" folder.

I know that someone was working on having the emails sent with Apps Script to show up in "sent" folder. Would you know how to implement this?

Comment: The problem was due to a bug. It's fixed now. See [issue 674](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=674) (link [provided](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12819880/1595451) by Henrique G. Abreu).

Answer (score 1):

[update] This issue is now solved.

The only workaround available is to bcc yourself. There's an [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=674) open regarding this. You should star it to keep track of updates and kind of vote for it.

Comment: Hi, I know that issue and I am following it.. but its taking so long.. where could I get a estimated time for this? I am currently bccing my self but it's reducing the quota of emails that I can send a day in gmail...

Comment: Only googlers could inform you this, but they never do. They're probably not allowed to. There's really nothing you can do about this. If I were you, I'd just consider that this will never be solved. And if someday it is, then it's a blessing. I have opened issues way older than this one (and probably with easier solutions) that are not solved. And this is not even a real issue, just an enhancement request.