# Emails sent via GmailApp api not appearing in users sent folder

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api

I have a script that is using GmailApp.sendEmail to create and send html emails.

The script is working fine and the emails are being sent and received at the other end, but the messages are not appearing within the users sent gmail label/folder.

Is it possible to make this happen, as I'd like the user to have some reassurance that the scrip has worked and be able to refer back to the sent mail in the future?

Many thanks,

Comment: Looks like old bug that was fixed already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818059/mails-sent-with-apps-script-dont-show-up-in-sent-folder?rq=1 Also try logging `Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail()` and checking that script is executed by correct user

Comment: When is the script run? is it a trigger, a button?

Comment: What account are they appearing in?  Perhaps they were not deployed to be run as user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your thoughts and suggestions. The article that Kos supplied leads to a [google issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753471) from several years ago where there is still some debate in the comments about whether or not it is actually resolved!

A workaround that is suggested is to bcc the user into the email. They will, therefore, be sent a copy of the mail as confirmation that it has worked:

```
GmailApp.sendEmail(to, subject, body, {htmlBody:body, from:administratorEmail, bcc:administratorEmail});
```

While this is not a particularly elegant solution, it appears to be the best option for now.

Many thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Alex! I think you should use this:

```
var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() //get Email of active user
GmailApp.sendEmail(mail, subject, message, {from: userEmail })
```